# Why unique_ptr doesn't prevent slicing of custom deleter?

Tags: c++, unique-ptr, object-slicing

The behavior of `std::unique_ptr` with `custom deleter` is based on the ***static type*** of the deleter. No polymorphism, no runtime behavior based on actual deleter passed in runtime, as derived deleter provided is being sliced to the static type of the declared deleter.

> (It is designed this way in purpose, to allow the size of unique_ptr with *`default deleter`* or with *`custom deleter without any data members`*, to have same size as a raw pointer).

### static behavior of `unique_ptr` with `custom deleter`:

```
class A {};

struct BaseDeleter {
    virtual void operator()(A* p) const {
        std::cout << "in BaseDeleter" << std::endl; 
        delete p;
    }
};

struct DerivedDeleter: BaseDeleter {
    void operator()(A* p) const override {
        std::cout << "in DerivedDeleter" << std::endl; 
        delete p;
    }
};

int main() {
    auto unique_var = std::unique_ptr<A, BaseDeleter>(new A);
    unique_var = std::unique_ptr<A, DerivedDeleter>(new A);
}
```

**Output:**

```
in BaseDeleter
in BaseDeleter
```

---

This is opposed to `std::shared_ptr` who holds its custom deleter differently and allowing dynamic behavior:

### dynamic behavior of `shared_ptr` with `custom deleter`:

```
int main() {
    auto shared_var = std::shared_ptr<A>(new A, BaseDeleter{});
    shared_var = std::shared_ptr<A>(new A, DerivedDeleter{});
}
```

**Output:**

```
in BaseDeleter
in DerivedDeleter
```

Code: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/54a8d2fc3c95d4c1

---

The behavior of assigning `std::unique_ptr` with different `custom deleter` is actually **slicing**.

## Why unique_ptr doesn't prevent slicing of custom deleter?

Why didn't the language block the assignment of `std::unique_ptr` if the assigned unique_ptr has different `custom deleter`, to avoid slicing?

---

This seems to be possible as presented below.

### Blocking `unique_ptr` from slicing of `custom deleter`

```
template<typename TYPE, typename Deleter>
struct my_unique_ptr : std::unique_ptr<TYPE, Deleter> {
    using BASE = std::unique_ptr<TYPE, Deleter>;
    using std::unique_ptr<TYPE, Deleter>::unique_ptr;
    auto& operator=(std::nullptr_t) noexcept {
        return BASE::operator=(nullptr);
    }
    template<typename T, typename OtherDeleter,
      std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same<OtherDeleter, Deleter>::value>* dummy = nullptr>
    auto& operator=(std::unique_ptr<T, OtherDeleter>&& other) = delete;
};
```

Code: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/089cd4c7303ad63e

Comment: My understanding - which may be incorrect - was that unique_ptr was optimized for its speed and memory footprint while shared_ptr was not. But perhaps I’m mistaken?

Comment: @templatetypedef blocking the option of accidentally slicing your deleter can be done in compile time, as proposed in the question

Comment: thanks for this question, i learned something new. lookinig forward to see the explanation.

Comment: Why block it? If the pointed to object can be polymorphically deleted, there is no issue.

Comment: @StoryTeller see my example inside, it leads to slicing of the deleter, you would actually not get polymorphic behavior of the deleter. Which is probably never what you actually intended if provided an object with a derived deleter. Thus blocking should be right I believe.

Comment: @AmirKirsh - It doesn't matter if we use the deleter of a base when the d'tor is virtual. That's what "polymorphic deletion" is. Not polymorphism of the deleter. Your idea will interfere with a basic use case.

Comment: @StoryTeller can't see any logical valid use case that would become invalid with my suggestion. If you have one this would be a good answer to this question I guess.

Comment: This looks more like a rant than a question, but anyway. With shared_ptr, the deleter resides with the **object** (in the control block). With unique_ptr, there is no control block, the deleter is stored **in the pointer itself** and is moved as the pointer gets passed around.

Comment: Blocking object slicing in this particular scenario doesn't seem any more justified than blocking it in any other scenario. I mean, slicing is bad, and eliminating it is a noble goal, but why start here?

Comment: @n.m. the different design of `unique_ptr` and `shared_ptr` as you rightfully present, may lead to undesired usage - as presented in the question. The bad usage could have been blocked by `unique_ptr`. Indeed there might be other bad scenarios elsewhere in the language (we are in C++ after all...). But I'm focusing on this one, which I believe could be improved, or maybe can still be improved without breaking any logical valid behavior. I think.

Comment: Custom deleters that form a public-inheritance class hierarchy are a mistake in the first place. Why would anyone want such a thing?

Comment: Slicing is not always a bad thing, sometimes it is the correct thing. Also this way allows the deleters to be *convertible* between types - not everything is (or even should be) polymorphic.

Comment: Also, if for some reason you need polymorphic deleters, you could create a deleter wrapper that holds a reference to the deleter to circumvent undesirable slicing.

Comment: Note the deleter is either copy- or move- constructed from the given deleter. (In your specific case, it is indeed sliced - in `std::default_delete` it isn't, it just uses its converting ctor). The fact that it can be copy- or move-constructed can be useful - indeed it is for `std::default_delete`, whose `operator()` just `delete`s the pointed-to object, which is safe when the base and derived classes have a virtual dtor. One could imagine similar custom deleters, which safely polymorphically delete (using a `delete` expression or in some other manner), and perhaps perform some record keeping.

Comment: @Danra if you can present such a custom deleter case, where unique_ptr base type would reach the derived deleter provided this would be a good answer for my original question. I wasn't able to produce a _simple_ polymorphic custom deleter. I posted a code review for a not so simple polymorphic custom deleter: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/229718/polymorphic-deleter-for-unique-ptr though I wonder if there is a simpler example.

Answer (score 3):

```
struct B {
  virtual ~B() = default;
};

struct D : B {};

std::unique_ptr<B> b;
b = std::make_unique<D>();
```

Here we have a classic use case. Yes, the deleter is sliced, but deletion is still well defined. Your proposal will interfere with that. And will probably be very hard to amend reliably into not interfering.

One can always specify a custom deleter like `std::function<void(void*)>` to get polymorphism by type erasure. Sure, it has overhead, but that's opt in.

By default `unique_ptr` is optimized for the more common use cases, with less common ones that require overhead being possible by request.

Comment: Yet, slicing can be allowed for `default deleter` and blocked for `custom deleter`. [http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/aa68c17f5ff06ac4](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/aa68c17f5ff06ac4)

Comment: @AmirKirsh - Ah, so if I designed my own custom deleter that is well behaved with polymorphism I can't use it because "reasons"? UB is a staple of C++. It is not a safe language, and trying to make it one only ends up crippling your intended audience.

Comment: I see no actual way to design a custom deleter that can be just sliced for another base deleter. Except for the default deleter which is a special case and can be handled separately. The cases where a user would slice a custom deleter would be a bug, always, I believe.
Should the language stop the user from doing that? If it can I believe it should.

Comment: @AmirKirsh - Well, then your stance is way more sure of itself compared to the committees. They tread far more carefully when blocking stuff, and still get a fair share of defect reports. The stance that slicing is always bad is way too extreme, in my not so humble opinion.

Comment: Just for the record, the use case of different implementations for same type of custom deleter is supported in my proposed code: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d4fd4c5e2536ee44